# Fail2Ban direct to website

Tags: debian, fail2ban

Is it possible to set fail2ban to direct banned ips to a webpage instead of breaking connection and getting the timed out errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your jail file you specify the action that Fail2Ban performs when it "bans" a host.  You can create an action file so it does something other than ban the ip address if you wish.  For example you could add a redirection rule rather than dropping the traffic.

Comment: This is correct. But what is the benefit? If you want to block a SSH login attack, will you redirect to another SSH host? Or a HTTP site? Blocking should be done carefully so that innocent people are not affected. If they are affected you were too restrictive.

Comment: The user does not specify the how he is using fail2ban.  There are scenarios in which it would be helpful to redirect banned users to a site explaining why they have been blocked.

Comment: Sure. Was a little bit or rhetorical from me. This is why a gave this short and harsh answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is the intention of fail2ban to block the connection. Otherwise one had probably called it fail2redirect.

Comment: Yeah I guess I will have to live with being updated by email. I dont want it to ban innocent users and them not be aware they have even been banned. Most users would just presume there was a problem with the user, which looks bad.